# No Terminal colors after hostname change

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, ssh

I have a VPS pre-installed with Ubuntu 14.04 version, it was my choice.

Can someone explain why after the host name change, terminal is no longer using colors?

I double tested that host name changing causes it. Also when I changed the host name back to original and reboot, the Colors didn't return. Why?

**UPDATE** after comment:

Fresh instance of VPS looks like this ls command:
[image]

Magically after hostname change, all coloring is lost (host name has been masked)
[image]

So far compared hidden files in /etc/skel/ and remain the same, but inspected only visually so maybe missed something.

**The core of this question is why lost colors, the answers on how to fix it are secondary concern, so please do not mark as duplicate.**

Comment: Can you provide an example of when it used to use colors?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Have you modified or deleted your /home/username/.bashrc? Cheers, Al

Comment: No, nothing, just renamed hostname, that's why is so unusual to me. I thought that maybe linux is doing the trick to let you know hostname has changed,, or maybe private key no longer valid due to hostname not matching. When restore to original initial name still no colors

Comment: The instance with colors has `colord` group, while the other has not, relevant?

Comment: Have you tried `ls -l --color="always"`?

Comment: @androiddev... that's why I asked about his .bashrc. That's where that alias is defined. Cheers, Al

Comment: @PawelCioch... in terminal, type 'grep "ls alias" .bash*', see what you get. Cheers, Al

Comment: re: grep "ls alias" .bash* I've got `.bashrc:# some more ls aliases`

Comment: using `ls --color="always"` gives colored list, why it stopped working after hostname change? :)

Comment: I think @heynnema meant to say "type `grep "alias ls" .bash*`"

Comment: @wjandrea... you're absolutely correct! Cheers, Al

Comment: `grep "alias ls" .bash*` result: `.bashrc:    alias ls='ls --color=auto'` but no colors when I type just `ls` so some alias is broken?